# Unity - How do I reset Inspector values for an ExecuteInEditMode script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get back to the default values without having to shutdown and restart Unity.

When I save in VSC the fields in the Inspector stay the same. The only way to get them to reset is to shutdown and restart Unity. Do I change code, a setting in Unity, or a setting in Visual Studio Code to get the Inspector panel and content back to original?

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DebugGizmos : MonoBehaviour
{
 [SerializeField]
 private float innerRadius = 1.0f;

 [SerializeField]
 private float outerRadius = 10.0f;

 [SerializeField]
 private float angle = 10.0f;

 [SerializeField]
 private float gap = 10.0f;

 [SerializeField]
 private int segments = 10;

 [SerializeField]
 private float height = 1;

 // Debugging var for drawing Gizmos
 private Vector3 vLI, vLO, vUI, vUO;
 private List<Vector3> liaPts, loaPts, uiaPts, uoaPts;

 void OnDrawGizmos()
 {
     GenerateWedge(innerRadius, outerRadius, angle, gap, segments, height);
     // if (!Application.isPlaying) return;

     for (var i=0; i < segments; i++)
     {
         Gizmos.color = Color.red;
         Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(liaPts[i], .1f); //lowerInner
         Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
         Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(uiaPts[i], .1f); //upperInner
         Gizmos.color = Color.green; 
         Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(loaPts[i], .1f); //lowerOuter
         Gizmos.color = Color.magenta;
         Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(uoaPts[i], .1f); //upperOuter
     }
 }

 ...and some helper functions.
```

Comment: If you click on the component options (usually a gear or three dots) you should be able to reset the component.

Comment: All that `[ExecuteInEditMode]` changes is that `Update`, `OnEnable` etc will get called also outside of playmode ... everything else just behaves like any other component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right Click on the Gear Icon in the Inspector where you script component is.

Then click on Reset.

That should make the values go back to their initial values.

Comment: That worked...Follow up. It reset to old values, ie I have updated the script to new values. When I reset it, Unity set the values to the ones from a state the files was in several saves before. Why isn't it picking up the new defaults?

Comment: @kalmdown I think there you need to set the "dirty state" to make it happen